# What does the following portion of PolicyKit-gnome mean?

Tags: c

I'm looking through the source code for the [PolicyKit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/PolicyKit-gnome/) package in gnome, and I've come across some code on line 568 of `./src/polkitgnomeauthenticationdialog.c` that I need a little help with

```
if (g_strv_length (dialog->priv->users) > 1)
```

It's part of a conditional statement that will determine which dialogue is shown to the user when asking them to authenticate themselves by entering their password. What I need help with is what `dialog->priv-.users` means. I know it's a NULL terminated string, since that's what `g_strv_lngth` operates on, and I gather it's something to do with privileged users, but the syntax is throwing me off a bit, specifically the `->`. A quick explanation of this line would be most appreciated.

For reference, the full conditional statement is

```
label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  if (g_strv_length (dialog->priv->users) > 1)
    {
          gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (label),
                                _("An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. "
                                  "Authentication as one of the users below is required to perform this action."));
    }
  else
    {
      if (strcmp (g_get_user_name (), dialog->priv->users[0]) == 0)
        {
          gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (label),
                                _("An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. "
                                  "Authentication is required to perform this action."));
        }
      else
        {
          gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (label),
                                _("An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. "
                                  "Authentication as the super user is required to perform this action."));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C,

```
ptr->memb
```

is wholly equivalent to

```
(*ptr).memb
```

Expanding,

```
dialog->priv->users
```

is the same as

```
(*(*dialog).priv).users
```

`dialog` has type `PolkitGnomeAuthenticationDialog *` and `dialog->priv` has type `PolkitGnomeAuthenticationDialogPrivate *`: they're both pointers to structures, hence the use of `->`.

Answer (score 1):

A '->' is used to dereference a pointer to struct, in this case it means "dereference the pointer to struct dialog and then dereference the pointer to struct priv", thus getting the value of the struct member 'users'

Answer (score 1):

Typically you see `->` in C when accessing a member data field of a pointer to a struct. It's short hand notation for "dereference the pointer and access this field", so for example, if I have:

```
struct Data* d
(*d).dataitem;
d->dataitem;
```

The last two items are equivalent.

You can find the definition of said object [here](http://git.gnome.org/browse/PolicyKit-gnome/tree/src/polkitgnomeauthenticationdialog.h#n43).